# PC Having Memory Issues

Tags: memory-management

So a few months ago I built my PC.

- The mobo is an ASUS ROG STRIX Z390-E.
- I have 4 sticks of Corsair Vengeance LPX DDR4 3.0GHz 8GiB.
- The CPU is an i9-9900k.
- I have a gold rated 1200w PSU in it as well with a Nvidia 2080.
- My storage is 3 Samsung 850 EVO SSDs. 1TB, 1TB, and 256GB for the Windows 10 OS.

Temps are definitely not an issue with the cooling in this build.

The issue I'm having is with memory loss. I'm having memory errors with Steam and Origin downloading games to whatever drive I download to (I've tried them all) and once every day or so lately my pc will randomly crash in the middle of watching youtube or playing a game and give the "error-memory management" blue screen.

I've ran tests with my RAM and it seems to check out fine.

I recently put in a Samsung 970 EVO Plus 500GB nvme nand drive and when I put everything on it, its fine only problem is that I cant seem to put install my OS on that drive.

Any suggestions as to what I may be overlooking?

Comment: What are the specific error messages?

Comment: First, if you haven't, remove and reseat all your RAM. Remove any overclocking and run at stock.

Comment: Since you have 4 sticks, you need to run your PC with one stick at a time and also the same stick in other slots one by one and check the behavior. It's a bit of permutation/combination kind of a thing but it might help you isolate the issue with RAM slot or RAM or anything else.

Comment: "I put in a Samsung 970 EVO Plus 500GB nvme nand drive and when I put everything on it, its fine".  To me this sounds as if the problem might be in the storage rather than in memory. Looking forward to the precise errors reports.

Comment: Your ram is overclocked or is native 3.0 Ghz?

Comment: Good generic point. Corsair makes native 3GHz modules though, which I only knew because I am using four of those myself.

Comment: yhea, i'm asking because z390-E does not support native 3.0 ghz memory, you can check in asus product specs. Using not supported ram can even work i think in rare cases but most likely with many problems. If the ram is oc on the contrary is possible that the set up is wrong and can cause memory issues.

Answer (score -1):

https://www.passmark.com/products/burnintest/

Try this.

Try testing with a different OS, like linux.

Try testing your memory on boot with a boot memory tester.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question should've been posted as a comment.

Comment: "PC Having Memory Issues"  <- This is not a question.
"Any suggestions as to what I may be overlooking?" <- this is.

Comment: "Not all questions can or should be answered here. Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which...

...are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem." https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer